# Connectorless USB on a PCB

Tags: pcb, usb, connector, eaglecad

I would like to make a board which can be plugged directly into the USB port of a computer, instead of using a separate male "USB-A" connector. I have seen this system used for very small USB memory keys, such as [this one](http://www.engadget.com/2007/03/15/kingmax-unveils-worlds-smallest-usb-flash-drive/). How would I lay out a PCB with such a "connector" built in?

I am using Eagle. Does anyone have a library for it? Can anyone suggest another way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Sparkfun Eagle Library ([pre-6.0](https://github.com/sparkfun/Old-SparkFun-Eagle-Library), [6.0+](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun-Eagle-Libraries)) has one. It's called "USBPCB".

Here's [a project using it](http://goodfet.sourceforge.net/hardware/goodfet31/).

Comment: You are right! It was staring me right in the face. Thanks bunches, the eagle library system can be annoying at times.

Comment: BTW, do you have any idea what the proper PCB thickness would be? It looks like it's at least 1mm, maybe more.

Comment: I'm not sure, I'd suggest contacting the author of the GoodFET project I posted

Comment: Btw I emailed Travis of GoodFET fame. He said that the GF31 is produced on a board with a thickness of 0.078". He also suggested to round up when performing metric conversion to 2mm.

Comment: @drxzc - For prototypes, I would err on the side of thinner PCB, and if needed, simply add some tape on the back-side to make it thicker. That way, you're going to get *something* that will work.

Comment: @drxzcl 1.6mm is what you generally get if you don't specifically ask for something else.

Answer (score 3):

For reference: I tried the SparkFun footprint one on a 2mm thick board, the result was unsatisfying: the connectors on PCB oxidized and the connection was faulty, I didn't get the problem right away, but such bizarre things as the computer recognizing my FT230X chip (Serial adapter) as a Microsoft Ballpoint Mouse and the computer mouse begun to jump everywhere and click randomly (very annoying). Once I scraped the metal it worked very well again, so no deal, get a proper connector.

Comment: It would work fine if you had the PCB properly gold-plated. I don't think anyone would think that the tinned board surface is really reliable over any sort of timeframe.

Comment: @Connor Wolf: absolutely, but PCB houses do not offer such services and one can much less do it at home, but it's how connectors should be made. This was a noob experiment since I haven't found anything beyond theory on the net, I sacrificed some of my time to confirm it. It's usable, but be careful.

Comment: What bizarre PCB house are you using? Pretty much every PCB house I have ever looked at offer gold-plating. It's not free, but I bet even the PCB house you use can gold-plate your board. Ask them!

Comment: @Connor Wolf: Then I learned something new today, I'm completely self taught when it comes to PCB making so information isn't easy to come by.

Comment: Most board-houses (any decent one, anyways) will have a big list of all the stuff they can do. Read it! Or better yet, read the documentation from several different board houses, and compare and contrast it. You can infer a lot about the ease and mechanics of making boards that way.

Comment: Not only it's easy to do gold plating at home (you buy off-the-shelf chemical kits for it), but many PCB houses do in fact offer it even for small quantities.

Comment: OSHPark do gold plating for free. You only get one thickness though (1.6 mm) which doesn't seem to be enough. Perhaps a small piece of shim metal could be soldered to the opposite side to make it thicker?

Comment: "such bizarre things as the computer recognizing my FT230X chip (Serial adapter) as a Microsoft Ballpoint Mouse and the computer mouse begun to jump everywhere and click randomly (very annoying)" are a software problem, and provide absolutely zero evidence of any circuit misbehavior.  Simply go into the serial port properties in Device Manager and disable "Serial Enumeration".  On newer chip/driver combinations (including yours) you can set a bit using FT_Prog such that the driver won't install `serenum.sys` in the first place, thus saving you the step of turning it off.

Comment: It should be noted that even commercial caseless usb plugs tend to be very iffy when it comes to working properly if plugged in and out a lot. gold plated or not.