# Reliability of edge connectors for production

Tags: pcb, connector, component-selection, production

I'm looking for an 6 pin .1 standard edge connector to program for production my board without any connector. And I cannot find the number of cycle [they](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/card-edge-connectors-edgeboard-connectors/1441939?FV=1680002%2Cfff40016%2Cfff80093%2C1600004&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500) can support.

Does anyone has used such connector for production ? In this case which one ?
I only managed to find on .05 sullins connector that they support 500 min cycles

Comment: This question is off-topic http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic we don't discuss electronic components selection. Why? because we would probably just to a digikey search or google search, which you probably have access to.

Comment: Well, I don't read it as a shopping question. He's not seeking for a specific product, he's questioning the reliability of it.

Comment: My link to digikey was to show the type of connector I was referring to. My problem was that in datasheets of the edge connector on the list haven't any reliability cycle numbers. So I  was looking for information/feedback on the reliability for this type of connector

Comment: Got an answer from AMP. 20 cycles for 0.4um gold and 50 for 0,8um gold. So not usable even for product small production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edge connector sockets, like you might put on a motherboard, are not designed for a large number of insertions.

If you want a way to make a temporary connection to pads on a board in a production environment, build a fixture that incorporates [pogo pins](https://www.mill-max.com/new_products/pages/spring-loaded-contacts), which are expressly designed for this kind of application.

I once used a [modified "dip clip"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/45694/11683) for a similar purpose in a low-volume production environment.

Answer (score 2):

They used to use edge connectors for cartridges on toys. If the contact area is large, it seems like they can hold up OK, but I can't give you an actual cycle count. I worked on one project where an edge connector was used on a toy, but it was not customer accessible. During product development, we used it a lot, but I doubt very many units got to 500 cycles. Never had a single failure that I can remember, though.